# Select elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I am new in Wolfram Math and I need a help in making a simple program. Let's suppose we have a list:

```
list = {{1, 11}, {2, 7}, {4, 2}, {7, 9}, {-2, 3}, {-1, 10}};
```

Now, I need to collect the first elements of sublists, but not all of them, only those whose second elements are larger than 8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
list = {{1, 11}, {2, 7}, {4, 2}, {7, 9}, {-2, 3}, {-1, 10}};

Select[list, #[[2]] > 8 &][[All, 1]]
```

> {1, 7, -1}

OR using `Pick`

```
Pick[list[[All, 1]], UnitStep[list[[All, 2]] - 8], 1]
```

> {1, 7, -1}

Comment: @Suro. You're welcome, glad I could help.

Comment: Wow! 
How about, when we say that list has 3 3l3mens in each sublist `list = {{1, 11, 3}, {2, 7, 4}, {4, 2, 5}, {7, 9, 9}, {-2, 3, 3}, {-1, 10, 5}};`. I would like to impose two conditions and get second and third element which satisfies this condition. How to do it? I wrote a code like this, but I don't know how to use it to get both 2nd and 3rd element:
`Select[list, #[[2]] > 8 && #[[3]] > 3 &]
Select[list, #[[2]] > 8 && #[[3]] > 3 &][[All, 1]]`

Answer (score 10):

```
list = {{1, 11}, {2, 7}, {4, 2}, {7, 9}, {-2, 3}, {-1, 10}};
Cases[list, {a_, b_} /; b > 8 :> a]
(* {1, 7, -1} *)
```

What I'm doing above is to use [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) to select only those sublists whose second element is greater than 8,

```
Cases[list, {a_, b_} /; b > 8]
(* {{1, 11}, {7, 9}, {-1, 10}} *)
```

The `/;` notation defines a [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html).  Then I'm applying a `:>` to make a replacement, in this case keeping only the first element, look at [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)

Comment: Wow! Another excellent answer.
Now, lets say that we have list which is like this `list={{1,11,3},{2,7,4},{4,2,5},{7,9,9},{-2,3,3},{-1,10,5}};`. Now I have to take out the second and third value in the sublist which satisfies the criteria b>8 and c>8. I would like to take out the value of b and c which satisfies this criterion. How to do this? I wrote a code, but its not working: `Cases[list,{a_,b_,c_}/;b>8:>b]
Cases[list,{a_,b_,c_}/;b>8:>c]
Cases[list,{a_,b_,c_}/;b>8&c>8:>b]`

Answer (score 4):

```
Pick[list[[All, 1]], # > 8 & /@ list[[All, 2]]]
```

or

```
Pick[#[[1]], # > 8 & /@ #[[2]]] &@Transpose[list]
```

> {1, 7, -1}

Comment: Nice one. But, how about this list `list={{1,11,3},{2,7,4},{4,2,5},{7,9,9},{-2,3,3},{-1,10,5}};` and taking out 2nd and 3rd element in each sublist which satisfies simultaneously 2 condition such that 2nd and 3rd element should be more than 8?

Comment: @sreerajt, you can try `Pick[#, #[[1]] > 8 && #[[2]] > 8 & /@ #] &@list[[All, {2, 3}]]` or `Select[#[[1]] > 8 && #[[2]] > 8 &]@list[[All, {2, 3}]]`  or ` Cases[_?(#[[1]] > 8 && #[[2]] > 8 &)]@list[[All, {2, 3}]]`.

Comment: many thank 4 dese excellent suggestions. But I do have a pblm in this: take 1st one. In this, what it does is dat it first picks out 2nd and 3rd elements from each sublist by `list[[All,{2,3}]]` and then apply the condition to check on **1st** & **2nd** element on **this modified list** (if you have a doubt you can check it by changing `#[[2]]` to `#[[3]]`-it gives an error).
How about a case where u check for condition on **1st** and **3rd** element of each sublist & then select 2nd and 3rd element in d sublist which satisfies this condition? This question applies to all ur sugestions

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica/Wolfram Language provides a lot of flexibility. Some ways you could do this:

```
Cases[list, {x_, _?(# > 8 &)} :> x]
Select[list, #[[2]] > 8 &][[;; , 1]]
Pick[list, #[[2]] > 8 & /@ list][[;; , 1]]
True /. GroupBy[list, (#[[2]] > 8 &) -> (#[[1]] &)]
Flatten[Last@Reap[Sow @@@ list, _?(# > 8 &), #2 &]]
```

I encourage you to look  the documentation and play. You can find the way that suits your aims and/or style.

and some more ridiculous:

```
Cases[{#1, Sign[#2 - 8]} & @@@ list, {x_, 1} :> x]
f[x_, y_] := x /; y > 8
f[__] := Sequence[]
f @@@ list
```

Comment: Your advice is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Region*` functionality:** (totally unnecessary here but ...)

```
list = {{1, 11}, {2, 7}, {4, 2}, {7, 9}, {-2, 3}, {-1, 10}};

reg = ImplicitRegion[y > 8, {x, y}];

Pick[list[[All, 1]], RegionMember[reg, list]]
Pick[list[[All, 1]], RegionWithin[reg, Point@#] & /@ list]
```

---

*Result:*

> {1, 7, -1}

Comment: (+1) Ingenious way of approaching the matter. Happy New Year, @Syed! :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 11}, {2, 7}, {4, 2}, {7, 9}, {-2, 3}, {-1, 10}};

f[n_][a_, b_] /; b > n := a
f[_][__] := Nothing

f[8] @@@ list
```

{1, 7, -1}

```
f[3] @@@ list
```

{1, 2, 7, -1}

Answer (score 2):

Using `Position` and `Extract`:

```
list = {{1, 11}, {2, 7}, {4, 2}, {7, 9}, {-2, 3}, {-1, 10}};

Extract[#, Position[#, {a_, b_} /; b > 8]] &@list

(*{{1, 11}, {7, 9}, {-1, 10}}*)
```

Or equivalently:

```
Extract[#, Position[#, x : {__} /; Last@x > 8]] &@list

(*{{1, 11}, {7, 9}, {-1, 10}}*)
```